# Redirect all users except me during maintenance

Tags: .htaccess

I have this very simple rule in my `.htaccess`. Basically, i want to redirect all users except me during maintenance. For some reason, it is also redirecting me to `maintenance.php`.

I don't have any other `.htaccess`.

The `.htaccess` is found on My document root: `/Users/myname/Sites`

```
# redirect to maintenance page
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^127\.0\.0\.1
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/maintenance.php$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /maintenance.php [R=302,L]
```

I've search and search here and tried pretty much everything for the last 3 days with no success. I cant find what it's wrong with this very simple piece of code? Anyone has any ideas?

If it helps, my `access_log` says something like:

```
::1 - - [07/Mar/2021:13:47:36 -0500] "GET /maintenance.php HTTP/1.1" 200 2956
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are redirected your self on /meintanence.php as logfile indicates. Please test this to avoid local request redirecting:

```
# redirect to maintenance page
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^::1
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/maintenance.php$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /maintenance.php [R=302,L]
```

::1 is the loopback address in IPv6, as the IPv4 version is 127.0.0.1.

Comment: @yeap, that did it! But why is it that my system isn't picking up `127.0.0.1`? This looks weird `::1`

Comment: apache2 uses IPv6 when you invoke https://localhost/...